Is there a way to automatically subtract the smallest from the greatest value in the same column in Excel?
Image sample

I have to subtract the smallest value from the greatest value of about a thousand groups of values like the ones in the screenshot. For example, for group 58 I have to subtract the first value (the smallest) from the last (the greatest). And do this a thousand times. Is there an automated way of doing this?
I played with the pivot table but I couldn't get it to find the smallest and the greatest values for each group.

maxifs() and minifs() may be worth trying.

A pivot table cannot do this. Depending on your Excel version, you can use a formula, PowerQuery, or VBA. Add the appropriate tags at the bottom of your post.
